# Laravel Elixir BrowserSync Proxy not Working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, browser-sync, laravel-elixir

I've just installed Laravel 5.3, it's a completely fresh install and after looking through the Docs i've set up my Gulpfile as follows:

```
elixir((mix) => {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack('app.js')
       .version(['css/app.css', 'js/app.js'])
       .browserSync({
         proxy: 'subdomain.mydomain.dev'
       });
});
```

For some reason every single time i run `gulp watch` it launches the browser towards `localhost:3000`

What am i doing wrong? Isn't this supposed to direct the BrowserSync to my Mamp Vhost if i set the address exactly the same?

Comment: It seems to have something to do with the `.dev` TLD... i still don't get why it's not working, i have to give up my dev tld to make BrowserSync work in Elixir? Seriously? :\

Comment: you don't want to run on localhost ??

Comment: have you tried `.browserSync('subdomain.mydomain.dev');`

Answer (score 1):

First, change your `.dev` domain to something different from a globally registered TLD, because lately `.dev` TLD is owned by google and it's requiring a SSL connection etc..

More details here: https://medium.engineering/use-a-dev-domain-not-anymore-95219778e6fd

You can initialize your browserSync module with some extra parameters like this:

```
.browserSync({
    proxy: 'subdomain.mydomain.tld',
    host: 'subdomain.mydomain.tld',
    open: 'external'
});
```

**host:** Override host detection if you know the correct IP to use

**open:** Decide which URL to open automatically when Browsersync starts. Defaults to "local" if none set.

If you can see your defined host in browsersync cli initialization message as external host, it should work.